# Using Intel oneAPI MKL to perform sparse matrix with dense vector multiplication

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, armadillo, intel-mkl

I am developing a program, making heavy use of Armadillo library. I have the 10.8.2 version, linked against Intel oneAPI MKL 2022.0.2. At some point, I need to perform many
sparse matrix times dense vector multiplications, both of which are defined using Armadillo structures. I have found this point to be a probable bottleneck, and was being curious if replacing the Armadillo multiplication with "bare bones" sparse CBLAS routines from MKL ([mkl_sparse_d_mv](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/inspector-executor-sparse-blas-routines/inspector-executor-sparse-blas-execution-routines/mkl-sparse-mv.html)) would speed things up. But in order to do so, I need to convert from Armadillo's SpMat to something that MKL understands. As per Armadillo docs, sparse matrices are stored in [CSC](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat) format, so I have tried
[mkl_sparse_d_create_csc](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/appendix-a-linear-solvers-basics/sparse-matrix-storage-formats/sparse-blas-csc-matrix-storage-format.html). My attempt at this is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include "mkl.h"

int main()
{

    arma::umat locations = {{0, 0, 1, 3, 2},{0, 1, 0, 2, 3}};
    // arma::vec vals = {0.5, 2.5, 2.5, 4.5, 4.5};
    arma::vec vals = {0.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5};
    arma::sp_mat X(locations, vals);
    std::cout << "X = \n" << arma::mat(X) << std::endl;
    arma::vec v = {1,1,1,1};
    arma::vec v2;
    v2.resize(4);

    std::cout << "v = \n" << v << std::endl;
    std::cout << "X * v = \n" << X * v << std::endl;

    MKL_INT *cols_beg = static_cast<MKL_INT *>(mkl_malloc(X.n_cols * sizeof(MKL_INT), 64));
    MKL_INT *cols_end = static_cast<MKL_INT *>(mkl_malloc(X.n_cols * sizeof(MKL_INT), 64));
    MKL_INT *row_idx = static_cast<MKL_INT *>(mkl_malloc(X.n_nonzero * sizeof(MKL_INT), 64));
    double *values = static_cast<double *>(mkl_malloc(X.n_nonzero * sizeof(double), 64));

    for (MKL_INT i = 0; i < X.n_cols; i++)
    {
        cols_beg[i] = static_cast<MKL_INT>(X.col_ptrs[i]);
        cols_end[i] = static_cast<MKL_INT>((--X.end_col(i)).pos());
        std::cout << cols_beg[i] << " --- " << cols_end[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (MKL_INT i = 0; i < X.n_nonzero; i++)
    {
        row_idx[i] = static_cast<MKL_INT>(X.row_indices[i]);
        values[i] = X.values[i];
        std::cout << row_idx[i] << " --- " << values[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    sparse_matrix_t X_mkl = NULL;
    sparse_status_t res = mkl_sparse_d_create_csc(&X_mkl, SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO,
                                                  X.n_rows, X.n_cols, cols_beg, cols_end, row_idx, values);

    if(res == SPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) std::cout << "Constructed mkl representation of X" << std::endl;
    matrix_descr dsc;
    dsc.type = SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL;

    sparse_status_t stat =  mkl_sparse_d_mv(SPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, 1.0, X_mkl, dsc, v.memptr(), 0.0, v2.memptr());
    std::cout << "Multiplication status = " << stat << std::endl;
    if(stat == SPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) 
    {
        std::cout << "Calculated X*v via mkl" << std::endl;
        std::cout << v2;
    }

    mkl_free(cols_beg);
    mkl_free(cols_end);
    mkl_free(row_idx);
    mkl_free(values);
    mkl_sparse_destroy(X_mkl);

    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling this code with (with the help of Link Line Advisor)
`icpc -g testing.cpp -o intel_testing.out -DARMA_ALLOW_FAKE_GCC -O3 -xhost -Wall -Wextra -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -DMKL_ILP64 -qmkl=parallel -larmadillo`
on Pop!_OS 21.10.
It compiles and runs without any problems. The output is as follows:

```
X = 
   0.5000   2.5000        0        0
   3.5000        0        0        0
        0        0        0   5.5000
        0        0   4.5000        0

v = 
   1.0000
   1.0000
   1.0000
   1.0000

X * v = 
   3.0000
   3.5000
   5.5000
   4.5000

0 --- 1
2 --- 2
3 --- 3
4 --- 4

0 --- 0.5
1 --- 3.5
0 --- 2.5
3 --- 4.5
2 --- 5.5

Constructed mkl representation of X
Multiplication status = 0
Calculated X*v via mkl
   0.5000
        0
        0
        0
```

As we can see, the result of Armadillo's multiplication is correct, whereas the one from MKL is wrong. My question is this: **Am I making a mistake somewhere? Or is there something wrong with MKL?**. I suspect the former of course, but after spending considerable amount of time, cannot find anything. Any help would be much appreciated!

#### EDIT

As CJR and Vidyalatha_Intel suggested, I have changed col_end to

```
 cols_end[i] = static_cast<MKL_INT>((X.end_col(i)).pos());
```

The result is now

```
X = 
   0.5000   2.5000        0        0
   3.5000        0        0        0
        0        0        0   5.5000
        0        0   4.5000        0

v = 
   1.0000
   1.0000
   1.0000
   1.0000

X * v = 
   3.0000
   3.5000
   5.5000
   4.5000

0 --- 2
2 --- 3
3 --- 4
4 --- 5

0 --- 0.5
1 --- 3.5
0 --- 2.5
3 --- 4.5
2 --- 5.5

Constructed mkl representation of X
Multiplication status = 0
Calculated X*v via mkl
   4.0000
   2.5000
        0
        0
```

col_end is indeed 2,3,4,5 as suggested, but the result is still wrong.

Comment: Your column pointer offsets are wrong and the only correctly indexed value in your resulting array is at `0,0`. If the offset for start and stop are the same, the column has length zero and no values.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? Is it the cols_beg or cols_end that is wrong. If so, how could I correct it?

Comment: The cols_end is wrong. It isn't inclusive. It should be 2,3,4,5

Comment: I have changed the code so that cols_end is 2,3,4,5 and the results are still wrong.

Comment: Your remark was of course correct, it turned out that -DMKL_ILP64 compilation flag was causing problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the cols_end array is incorrect as pointed out by CJR. They should be indexed as 2,3,4,5. Please see the documentation regarding the parameter to the function mkl_sparse_d_create_csc

cols_end:

> This array contains col indices, such that cols_end[i] - ind - 1 is the last index of col i in the arrays values and row_indx. ind takes 0 for zero-based indexing and 1 for one-based indexing.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/inspector-executor-sparse-blas-routines/matrix-manipulation-routines/mkl-sparse-create-csc.html

Change this line

> cols_end[i] = static_cast<MKL_INT>((--X.end_col(i)).pos());

to

> cols_end[i] = static_cast<MKL_INT>((X.end_col(i)).pos());

Now recompile and run the code. I've tested it and it is showing the correct results. Image with results and compilation command
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have changed the col_end exactly as you and CJR pointed out. The result is now [4.0000 2.5000 0 0], which is still incorrect.

Comment: Could you please try with the compilation command which is provided in the image and check it once. /usr/include/ is the location of armadillo in my system.

Comment: Okay, I've run some test with different compiler flags, and found out that -DMKL_ILP64 is the culprit. Do you happen to know what this flag is responsible for? Either way, thank you for helping me!

Comment: Maybe you can go through this link https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-linux-developer-guide/top/linking-your-application-with-onemkl/linking-in-detail/linking-with-interface-libraries/using-the-ilp64-interface-vs-lp64-interface.html for better understanding of ILP64/LP64 interfaces. Testing with -DMKL_LP64 option also gives correct results. "Linking of an application compiled with the -i8 or -DMKL_ILP64 option to the LP64 libraries may result in unpredictable consequences and erroneous output." Hope it helps.